# removing character after 3 different specific characters

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have a problem to get a result as example below using oracle. I have a lot of different data in a field A, and need to do a few step (as below) to become a result in field B.

example:
`LM2963NAMBLK-P/NOPB/SA`  and the result: `LM2963NAM`

1. remove all characters after `'/'`
2. remove character  `'-P'`
3. remove character  `'BLK'`

Comment: This is not clear at all. What do you mean by "remove character" - remove ONE character, or ALL the characters after the "marker"? Then, do you need to execute three removals, in that order? What happens if you have more than one '/' in the input string? And, it seems you remove the "marker" **and** the character (or characters) from the string, not only the character **after** the 3 different specific "markers". You can't get a good answer to an "approximate" (unclear, confusing) problem.

Comment: yes..my mistake for the unclear problem. it should remove all the characters for the filed after the "marker". usually, when using m.excel 1step : I will delimited "/" for the field
2step: if the field have "-P" i will remove it by using this formula =IF(RIGHT(A2,2)="-P",LEFT(A2,LEN(A2)-2),A2) then 3rd step: remove "BLK" using this formula =IF(RIGHT(B2,3)="BLK",LEFT(B2,LEN(B2)-3),B2) to get the final result.

Comment: Thanks to all .. comment @Wistful Thinker is success to me.               select A,
  regexp_replace( regexp_replace(A, '-P|/.*', ''), '^(.*)BLK$', '\1' ) B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below should work:

```
select A,
  regexp_replace(
    regexp_replace(A, '-P|/.*', ''),
    '^(.*)BLK$', '\1'
    ) B
--remainder of query
```

The nested regexp_replace will replace -P or / followed by 0 or more occurrences of any characters with the empty string, leaving you with your desired output plus a possible BLK at the end.  The | represents "or."  I'm not logged in to oracle at the moment, but the - and / shouldn't need to be escaped as / is not a special character in Oracle regex and - is only a special character inside of [ ].  The outside regexp_replace will replace BLK at the end with the empty string if it is there, or just return your string if it is not there.

Comment: Thank You !! I get the result as I want .

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is one way...

```
  select substr( substr( substr( 'LM2963NAMBLK-P/NOPB',1, slash_pos-1 ), 1, dash_p_pos-1 ), 1, blk_pos-1 )
  from
  (
  select 'LM2963NAMBLK-P/NOPB'
     , instr( 'LM2963NAMBLK-P/NOPB', '/' ) slash_pos
     , instr( 'LM2963NAMBLK-P/NOPB', '-P' ) dash_p_pos
     , instr( 'LM2963NAMBLK-P/NOPB', 'BLK' ) blk_pos
  from dual
  );

SUBSTR(SU
---------
LM2963NAM
```

Comment: Thanks. but my problem still not settle. I need to remove the characters for all row in the column.